# getting real path of file on samba server from client

Tags: samba

I would like to know if it is possible to get the real path of a file on a samba server from a Mac or Windows client.

Looking into the source code of samba, there is a function call vfs_realpath. I am not sure how this can be triggered.

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://serverfault.com/questions/815476/getting-real-path-of-file-on-samba-server-from-client). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. it's not possible by design.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for this?

Comment: source code is the reference